# Why is it physically impossible to heat something higher than Planck's Temperature (absolute hot)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Why can't we just keep heating matter past Planck's temperature? Planck's temperate or 10 to the power of 32 Kelvin is the hottest temperature possible. If you're shooting an atom with heat radiation and it reaches Planck's temperate why can't you keep heating it.

I do have a theory though - Lets say you're shooting an electron with a laser and heating it up. Every time an electron goes into a higher quantum state it requires more energy to bring it into the next one. At first the difference of energy required is not noticeable but eventually it requires more and more energy to further excite the electrons of the atom(s) being heated. After a long time some of the electrons are at such high energy levels that they require infinite energy to go into a higher quantum state.

Comment: It isn't. That's it.

Comment: Where does it say that we can't? The Planck scale is, at this time, nothing but a speculation.

Comment: @CuriousOne  Not a speculation, but very often misunderstood in popular science books.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy: Can you cite a single measurement done at the Planck scale?

Comment: The other question was more focused on kinetic energy and the speed at which particles vibrate. He asked if there was a hottest temperature possible, I'm asking why can't we go hotter than that temperature.

Comment: @CuriousOne Pick up a grain of sand and feel its weight. Now remember that the sand grain is about a Planck mass, and nothing can be lighter than a Planck mass, right?

Comment: @immibis things can be lighter than plank mass, that's the maximum  mass capable of holding a charge.

Comment: @immibis: I was asking about the Planck scale, not about one Planck mass. After all, we are also living on a pea size black hole... :-)

Comment: @EasyPeasy "That's the maximum mass capable of holding a charge" - this capacitor in my left hand says different. (Each plate holds a charge and weighs more than a Planck mass, even though the capacitor doesn't hold a net charge)

Comment: he Planck mass is the maximum allowed mass capable of holding a single elementary charge. - A single elementary charge

Comment: @EasyPeasy source? Why is this capacitor plate not capable of holding a single elementary charge, even though it's capable of holding more than one?